# How to set valid date or empty field in Symfony forms constraints

Tags: php, forms, symfony, date, constraints

how to validate date with constraints to allow date in format yyyy-mm-dd or leave date blank in this code?

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType {

    public function getName() {
        return 'article';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('date', 'date', array(
                    'label' => 'Date',
                    'input' => 'string',
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new Assert\NotBlank(),
                        new Assert\Date(),
                    ),
                ))

    }

}
```

Is it possible to validate without create custom validator?

Comment: All validators allow a null value by default. Just remove the NotBlank assert and it should work.

Comment: I've deleted "new Assert\NotBlank()" and got "Warning: IntlDateFormatter::parse(): Date parsing failed".

It must be "text" field type instead of "date".